# IIS web platform installer shows some components are installed but they are not, why?

Tags: php, iis, web-platform-installer

I have used `iis web platform installer` to install `PHP 7.3(x86)` and `PHP 7.3(x64)` on my `windows 10`.
Later I have deleted them, but I can still see them marked as installed in `web platform installer`.
[image]

Also when I open `FastCGI` settings I can't find any path accosiated with `php`.

[Here](https://forums.iis.net/t/1221976.aspx?Uninstall%20via%20Web%20Platform%20Installer) it is explained why there is no uninstall feature in `web platform installer` at all, but
How can I `"Remove"` them or mark as `"uninstalled"` in order I was able to install them again normally using `web platform installer`?

Comment: "Later I have deleted them". How? Those are MSI packages, so you need to uninstall from Control Panel/Programs.

Comment: Yes, i have uninstalled them from the Control Panel, and I hoped I would be able to install them using `web platform installer` again, but I couldn't.